# Running sql migrations of create extension in jest parallel triggers a constraint error

Tags: sql, jestjs, prisma

I'm using [Prisma 2](https://www.prisma.io/) as my ORM. Both for migrations and querying.

I have a `createTestContext` helper which among other things, it initializes Prisma by:

1. Creating a new schema
2. deploying migrations by running `./node_modules/.bin/prisma migrate deploy --preview-feature` (in nutshell it runs all of the migrations in my project directory).

On each test, I create a new `TestContext` to make sure there won't be any side effects. But the problem is, since all of my tests are running in parallel, all of them are running at the same time on a database this migration:

```sql
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis
```

Which triggers the following error:

```
Unique constraint failed on the fields: (`extname`)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how to fix this properly, but a current workaround is to capture the `unique_violation` exception and do nothing with it:

```sql
DO
$$
BEGIN
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS postgis;
EXCEPTION
WHEN unique_violation
    THEN NULL;
END;
$$
```